# Recently added drive not showing full capacity

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-disk, raid

I've been running a JBOD raid with a hardware controller and recently added two new drives.  The partition was set up to span the full set of disks, and the RAID rebuilt fine.  The trouble i'm having is lsblk is showing a full 27.3 TB (as expected, 3x10TB) but df -h only shows 9.1TB

```
core@Colossus:/mnt/data/docker/sonarr$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  3.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       915G   28G  841G   4% /
tmpfs           7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1       6.5T  1.2T  5.0T  20% /mnt/data/media/movies
/dev/sdb4       1.3T   36K  1.3T   1% /mnt/data/photos
/dev/sdb3       1.6T  397G  1.1T  27% /mnt/data/media/music
/dev/sdb5       3.7T  1.7T  1.9T  49% /mnt/data/torrents
/dev/sdb6       1.4T  872M  1.3T   1% /mnt/data/nexcloud
/dev/sdb2       1.9T  639G  1.2T  35% /mnt/data/media/anime
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1       9.1T  7.8T  849G  91% /mnt/data/media/tv
core@Colossus:/mnt/data/docker/sonarr$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 930.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0  16.4T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   6.5T  0 part /mnt/data/media/movies
├─sdb2   8:18   0   1.9T  0 part /mnt/data/media/anime
├─sdb3   8:19   0   1.5T  0 part /mnt/data/media/music
├─sdb4   8:20   0   1.3T  0 part /mnt/data/photos
├─sdb5   8:21   0   3.7T  0 part /mnt/data/torrents
└─sdb6   8:22   0   1.3T  0 part /mnt/data/nexcloud
sdc      8:32   0  27.3T  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0  27.3T  0 part /mnt/data/media/tv
core@Colossus:/mnt/data/docker/sonarr$
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Output of `file -s /dev/sdc1`:

```
/dev/sdc1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=33a92bb7-0a18-4c89-8004-77c9d90ecc8b, volume name "tvshows" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

Comment: `df` shows the size of the filesystem. `lsblk` shows the size of the partition. A filesystem in a partition may be smaller than the partition. You have expanded the partition, now it's time to expand the filesystem. What is the type of the filesystem inside `sdc1`? `mount` or `file -s /dev/sdc1` may tell you this. Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: @Andrew ... did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

If the steps you described are ALL you did you're most likely missing a `resize2fs` ...

```
resize2fs /dev/sdc1
```

This can normally be done on the fly, it might work a tick faster if you unmount `/dev/sdc1` first.

**Of course, all this is assuming that you're using `ext4`. For other filesystems there will be equivalent tools.**